# Django setup_test_environment in the shell causes Python to quit

Tags: python, django, shell

I'm following the basic Django tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial05/)

From within my project directory, I start the shell like so:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then

```
>>> from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
>>> setup_test_environment()
```

But as soon as I hit enter, python quits:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

And I'm given these details:

```
Process:         Python [57986]
Path:            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         2.7.5 (2.7.5)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [57491]
Responsible:     Terminal [21808]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-11-08 16:51:01.882 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  8028370E-0418-6FCE-8E0D-710AECAD680C

Sleep/Wake UUID: CAAC62F3-EFB9-42B8-A675-555E35708FAE

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100001000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   readline.so                     0x00000001027f4f97 call_readline + 647
1   org.python.python               0x0000000100008e22 PyOS_Readline + 274
2   org.python.python               0x00000001000b8315 builtin_raw_input + 597
3   org.python.python               0x00000001000c35fd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25213
4   org.python.python               0x00000001000c58c9 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
5   org.python.python               0x00000001000c31bd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24125
6   org.python.python               0x00000001000c58c9 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
7   org.python.python               0x00000001000c31bd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24125
8   org.python.python               0x00000001000c58c9 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
9   org.python.python               0x00000001000c31bd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24125
10  org.python.python               0x00000001000c58c9 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
11  org.python.python               0x000000010003e510 function_call + 176
12  org.python.python               0x000000010000c932 PyObject_Call + 98
13  org.python.python               0x00000001000be63d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 4797
14  org.python.python               0x00000001000c58c9 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
15  org.python.python               0x000000010003e510 function_call + 176
16  org.python.python               0x000000010000c932 PyObject_Call + 98
17  org.python.python               0x00000001000be63d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 4797
18  org.python.python               0x00000001000c58c9 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
19  org.python.python               0x000000010003e510 function_call + 176
20  org.python.python               0x000000010000c932 PyObject_Call + 98
21  org.python.python               0x00000001000be63d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 4797
22  org.python.python               0x00000001000c3fed PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27757
23  org.python.python               0x00000001000c3fed PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27757
24  org.python.python               0x00000001000c58c9 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
25  org.python.python               0x00000001000c31bd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24125
26  org.python.python               0x00000001000c58c9 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2137
27  org.python.python               0x00000001000c59e6 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
28  org.python.python               0x00000001000ea28e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
29  org.python.python               0x00000001000ea52a PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458
30  org.python.python               0x00000001001014ed Py_Main + 3101
31  org.python.python               0x0000000100000f14 0x100000000 + 3860

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000100364120  rcx: 0x0000000100300000  rdx: 0x0000000000003200
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00000001027f5254  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfd650  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfd580
   r8: 0x0000000100300000   r9: 0x00000000000006da  r10: 0x0000000002000003  r11: 0x0000000000000001
  r12: 0x0000000000000001  r13: 0x0000000000000019  r14: 0x00007fff5fbfd610  r15: 0x00007fff5fbfd590
  rip: 0x00000001027f4f97  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     5
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100000fff +org.python.python (2.7.5 - 2.7.5) <29DAB82B-5BC9-56CE-C09D-AE442FB37EF0> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x100003000 -        0x10016ffff +org.python.python (2.7.5, [c] 2004-2013 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.5) <CDFB33CA-71DD-B1C2-5262-545F3FA06153> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x1002f1000 -        0x1002f5fff +_collections.so (???) <C3759257-D3E2-1A2D-5B6D-F5CE2BAD59F1> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
       0x1002fb000 -        0x1002fcff7 +_heapq.so (???) <E4381E05-EEF3-6948-2616-3133F9266C5B> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
       0x1022f0000 -        0x1022f4ff7 +operator.so (???) <8203644B-B77C-2E1C-A0AF-614C0E9FA0CC> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
       0x1022fb000 -        0x1022fcff7 +_functools.so (???) <B0EB3CA3-1D94-8F0F-C2CE-4FB7651C9EB4> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
       0x102400000 -        0x102407ff7 +itertools.so (???) <8B7B7425-93EC-2588-DEA6-9CBE9FB670E8> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x102412000 -        0x102415ff7 +strop.so (???) <EF084977-083D-4241-3E1C-F784D1EC6BC2> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
       0x10245a000 -        0x10245cfff +_locale.so (???) <C498D276-0D22-5EB7-0332-8FD47164BCC5> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
       0x102460000 -        0x102464fff +_struct.so (???) <C5DCD024-216C-FA09-AE53-F5C308DC7EE0> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
       0x1024ab000 -        0x1024b9ff7 +datetime.so (???) <6F932ED3-23A3-53F7-CAAB-6E532A327C13> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
       0x1025f2000 -        0x1025f7fff +math.so (???) <DBF975FC-2716-ADD3-6911-5D951CB0DB61> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
       0x1025fe000 -        0x102600ff7 +time.so (???) <71BBC363-EB64-7E83-016A-85019ABE11A9> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
       0x102645000 -        0x10264eff7 +_socket.so (???) <695EB730-7782-CEC0-96D7-C82415A58249> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
       0x10265a000 -        0x10265eff7 +_ssl.so (???) <F11C5431-BBBC-472E-1D78-F3FEAA774381> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
       0x102664000 -        0x102665fff +cStringIO.so (???) <84827C5D-2394-D102-142B-87FBAD4A785A> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
       0x10266a000 -        0x10266dfef +binascii.so (???) <B1341D2E-EC17-A209-F850-C3CFDDDFCFD6> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
       0x1026b1000 -        0x1026b1fff +_scproxy.so (???) <2635F535-7B37-6190-16D7-FAC536366A2D> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.so
       0x1026b4000 -        0x1026b7fff +select.so (???) <81AE4135-7CD3-5C92-D8BA-8B6ADF4F866A> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
       0x1026bd000 -        0x1026beff7 +fcntl.so (???) <65448CBF-233E-1A16-976B-7C02357CFAAE> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.so
       0x102701000 -        0x102702fff +_hashlib.so (???) <F3E00F49-7684-BCA0-3053-6E36EEED082A> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
       0x102706000 -        0x102707fff +_random.so (???) <479693CA-BFEF-F888-1CE7-9BD4FD43BBAA> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_random.so
       0x10278a000 -        0x102799fff +cPickle.so (???) <72BD5DBF-624F-B0F4-0783-F75BB293F602> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cPickle.so
       0x1027a1000 -        0x1027b6ff7 +_io.so (???) <AC3AF946-5DCF-662C-0DC7-5F57FDD3CD4B> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
       0x1027ce000 -        0x1027d3fff +_json.so (???) <E4EE27AB-C49E-6A19-B603-1DA85AD3AF1E> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.so
       0x1027d8000 -        0x1027dbff7 +zlib.so (???) <7627B90E-3DA2-DE67-F574-CBE4F8816949> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so
       0x1027e0000 -        0x1027e5fff +array.so (???) <142AB497-D764-55A8-7FDB-D2A154D3054E> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
       0x1027ed000 -        0x1027edfff +_bisect.so (???) <6FA6B60B-13DC-2E86-D409-628062C08CAC> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
       0x1027f0000 -        0x1027f0fff +grp.so (???) <0F086696-FDA8-FABD-5051-D2B342BB56A6> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/grp.so
       0x1027f3000 -        0x1027f5ff7 +readline.so (???) <6EA1FE1F-B78C-23EF-A4C2-9B7E9FB8B643> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
       0x105080000 -        0x105114fef +unicodedata.so (???) <6C701F70-D60D-E225-74D2-C8A0A7651DA5> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so
       0x1054c0000 -        0x105562ff7 +_sqlite3.so (???) <E90E5264-66AD-9194-19E2-74231C7F9B84> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
       0x1059c0000 -        0x1059deffb  libedit.2.dylib (39) <1B0596DB-F336-32E7-BB9F-51BF70DB5305> /usr/lib/libedit.2.dylib
       0x1059ef000 -        0x105a43fe7 +libncursesw.5.dylib (5) <3F0079C0-01C1-3CB8-19CA-F9B49AA4F4A4> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libncursesw.5.dylib
    0x7fff66402000 -     0x7fff66435817  dyld (239.3) <D1DFCF3F-0B0C-332A-BCC0-87A851B570FF> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8b52f000 -     0x7fff8b57dfff  libcorecrypto.dylib (161.1) <F3973C28-14B6-3006-BB2B-00DD7F09ABC7> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8b6dd000 -     0x7fff8b6e1fff  libsystem_stats.dylib (93.1.26) <B9E26A9E-FBBC-3938-B8B7-6CF7CA8C99AD> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff8b6e2000 -     0x7fff8b716fff  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (50) <B15F967C-B002-36C2-9621-3456D8509F50> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8ba31000 -     0x7fff8bc16ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 855.11) <E22C6A1F-8996-349C-905E-96C3BBE07C2F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8c15e000 -     0x7fff8c165fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <4CD916B2-1B17-362A-B403-EF24A1DAC141> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff8c304000 -     0x7fff8c30dff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (121) <52571EC3-6894-37E4-946E-064B021ED44E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8c7a6000 -     0x7fff8c82fff7  libsystem_c.dylib (997.1.1) <61833FAA-7281-3FF9-937F-686B6F20427C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff8d0af000 -     0x7fff8d0caff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (23.1.10) <FFE5C472-B23A-318A-85BF-77CDE61900D1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff8d6eb000 -     0x7fff8d6ecfff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25) <334A82F4-4AE4-3719-A511-86D0B0723E2B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff8d6fd000 -     0x7fff8d704ff7  liblaunch.dylib (842.1.4) <FCBF0A02-0B06-3F97-9248-5062A9DEB32C> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8d8e2000 -     0x7fff8d945ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.13 - 1.13) <F05F4149-981B-380B-8F50-51CE804BBB89> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff8ddb3000 -     0x7fff8dde2fd2  libsystem_m.dylib (3047.16) <B7F0E2E4-2777-33FC-A787-D6430B630D54> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff8e842000 -     0x7fff8e853ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (217.1.4) <655FB343-52CF-3E2F-B14D-BEBF5AAEF94D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff8e854000 -     0x7fff8e87dff7  libc++abi.dylib (48) <8C16158F-CBF8-3BD7-BEF4-022704B2A326> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8eb06000 -     0x7fff8eb07ff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <4CDB0F7B-C0AF-3424-BC39-495696F0DB1E> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff8eb08000 -     0x7fff8eb09ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (63) <FB856CD1-2AEA-3907-8E9B-1E54B6827F82> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8eb12000 -     0x7fff8eb1cfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60049) <8C4F0CA0-389C-3EDC-B155-E62DD2187E1D> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff91676000 -     0x7fff91677ffb  libremovefile.dylib (33) <3543F917-928E-3DB2-A2F4-7AB73B4970EF> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff916a2000 -     0x7fff9184ff27  libobjc.A.dylib (551.1) <AD7FD984-271E-30F4-A361-6B20319EC73B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff91b18000 -     0x7fff91b20fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (522.1.11) <270DCF6C-502D-389A-AA9F-DE4624A36FF7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff91c66000 -     0x7fff91c67fff  libunc.dylib (28) <62682455-1862-36FE-8A04-7A6B91256438> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff924f2000 -     0x7fff92534ff7  libauto.dylib (185.5) <F45C36E8-B606-3886-B5B1-B6745E757CA8> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff92e90000 -     0x7fff92eb7ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (241.3) <8B1E1F1D-A5CC-3BAE-8B1E-ABC84337A364> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff92eb8000 -     0x7fff92edcfff  libxpc.dylib (300.1.17) <4554927A-9467-365C-91F1-5A116989DD7F> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff932d8000 -     0x7fff932dbff7  libdyld.dylib (239.3) <62F4D752-4089-31A8-8B73-B95A68893B3C> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff9332e000 -     0x7fff9333fff7  libz.1.dylib (53) <42E0C8C6-CA38-3CA4-8619-D24ED5DD492E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff938ed000 -     0x7fff938f1ff7  libcache.dylib (62) <BDC1E65B-72A1-3DA3-A57C-B23159CAAD0B> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff938f2000 -     0x7fff938f2ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <3AA8D85D-CF00-3BD3-A5A0-E28E1A32A6D8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff938f3000 -     0x7fff938f8fff  libmacho.dylib (845) <1D2910DF-C036-3A82-A3FD-44FF73B5FF9B> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff93e3b000 -     0x7fff93e42ff3  libcopyfile.dylib (103) <5A881779-D0D6-3029-B371-E3021C2DDA5E> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff9526d000 -     0x7fff9527dfff  libbsm.0.dylib (33) <2CAC00A2-1352-302A-88FA-C567D4D69179> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff95326000 -     0x7fff95328ff7  libquarantine.dylib (71) <7A1A2BCB-C03D-3A25-BFA4-3E569B2D2C38> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff95454000 -     0x7fff95470ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2422.1.72) <D14913DB-47F1-3591-8DAF-D4B4EF5F8818> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff9547a000 -     0x7fff95559fff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (50) <B95B9DBA-39D3-3EEF-AF43-44608B28894E> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff9683c000 -     0x7fff96856fff  libdispatch.dylib (339.1.9) <46878A5B-4248-3057-962C-6D4A235EEF31> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff96ba8000 -     0x7fff96badff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <78DCC358-2FC1-302E-B395-0155B47CB547> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff96ee0000 -     0x7fff96f10fff  libncurses.5.4.dylib (42) <BF763D62-9149-37CB-B1D2-F66A2510E6DD> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff96f4c000 -     0x7fff96f4dff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (278.10) <A47E7E11-3C76-318E-B67D-98972B86F094> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff96f5c000 -     0x7fff97114ff3  libicucore.A.dylib (511.25) <3ED7B656-416E-3071-AEC8-E85C90232F78> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff9712c000 -     0x7fff97132ff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (24.1.4) <331BA4A5-55CE-3B95-99EB-44E0C89D7FB8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff97305000 -     0x7fff9730cff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (53.1.4) <AB498556-B555-310E-9041-F67EC9E00E2C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff974a2000 -     0x7fff974a4ff3  libsystem_configuration.dylib (596.12) <C4F633D9-94C8-35D9-BB2D-84C5122533C7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff97e86000 -     0x7fff97e87ff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <BFC0DC97-46C6-3BE0-9983-54A98734897A> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff97e88000 -     0x7fff97eafffb  libsystem_info.dylib (449.1.3) <7D41A156-D285-3849-A2C3-C04ADE797D98> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff985f5000 -     0x7fff98647fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <4F68DFC5-2077-39A8-A449-CAC5FDEE7BDE> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 116595
    thread_create: 424
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=80.5M resident=13.2M(16%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=67.4M(84%)
Writable regions: Total=93.3M written=15.2M(16%) resident=20.4M(22%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=72.9M(78%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             84.8M
MALLOC (admin)                       16K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                          12K
__DATA                             2016K
__LINKEDIT                         66.4M
__TEXT                             14.1M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             231.8M

Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B02, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 1024 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug for Python 2.7.5 on Mavericks.  It will be fixed in Python 2.7.6. For more information see the big report.

http://bugs.python.org/issue18458